# Как получить размер памяти видеокарты?

Tags: ассемблер, fasm, видеокарта

Столкнулся с проблемой чтения объёма памяти видеокарты средствами Win32-API. Может кто знает способы? На запрос WMI вида `wmic.exe PATH Win32_videocontroller GET AdapterRAM` система возвращает размер памяти графической карты, но с ограничением в 4Gb. Этот-же самый порог определяется и в реестре. Но сейчас есть карты с памятью в 8 и более гигов, поэтому вариант не подходит. И вообще желательно на чистом WinAPI.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38163239/407561

Comment: @NMD, по вашей ссылке этот-же запрос WMI, который я привёл выше.

Comment: Почитай комментарии в нём

Comment: Метки [fasm] и [ассемблер] вероятно можно убрать?

Comment: @Kromster, просто код у меня на асме был, поэтому я отметил так. Да в принципе можно и убрать.

Comment: Если был код на asm, то может быть хорошо его приложить к вопросу тоже, для справки (если он не очень велик)

Answer (score 1):

После долгих поисков нашёл всё-таки решение вопроса при помощи функции `D3DKMTQueryAdapterInfo()`. Чтобы получить размер памяти видео свыше 4 Gb, нужно проделать следующие шаги:

1. `CM_Get_Device_Interface_List()` из setupapi.dll, чтобы получить системное имя адаптера. Во-втором параметре передаём ей константу "**GUID_DISPLAY_DEVICE_ARRIVAL**", а в последнем - флаг "**CM_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_LIST_PRESENT**" =0. Так мы получим имя только активного адаптера, а не всех когда-либо установленных.
2. `MultiByteToWideChar()` преобразует полученное имя из ANSI в Unicode, т.к. сл.функции требуется именно Unicode.
3. Теперь это имя передаём функции `D3DKMTOpenAdapterFromDeviceName()`, чтобы получить дескриптор видеоадаптера. В качестве параметра функция ожидает следующую структуру, и в неё-же возвращает дескриптор и LUID:

```
struct D3DKMT_OPENADAPTERFROMDEVICENAME
  pDeviceName               dd  0  ;// In. линк на Unicode-имя адаптера
  hAdapter                  dd  0  ;// Out. "D3DKMT_HANDLE"
  AdapterLuid               dq  0  ;// Out. LUID
ends
```

4. `D3DKMTQueryAdapterInfo()` указав ей тип запроса "**KMTQAITYPE_GETSEGMENTSIZE**" =3. В единственном параметре функция так-же ожидает указатель на структуру, все поля которой мы должны предварительно заполнить:

```
struct D3DKMT_QUERYADAPTERINFO
  hAdapter                  dd  0  ;// In. D3DKMT_HANDLE (Дескриптор адаптера, о котором извлекается информация)
  Type                      dd  0  ;// In. KMTQUERYADAPTERINFOTYPE (тип информации, которую нужно получить)
  pPrivateDriverData        dd  0  ;// In.Out. указатель на приёмный буфер
  PrivateDriverDataSize     dd  0  ;// In. размер буфера в байтах
ends
```

Обратите внимание, что данная функция может возвращать 47 типов информации об адаптере, который указывается в параметре "**Type**" структуры. От запрашиваемого типа зависит и возврат функции, поэтому в последнем параметре "**PrivateDriverDataSize**" нужно указывать строго валидный размер ожидаемых на выходе данных, иначе функция будет возвращать ошибку "Invalid Parameter" `0xC000000d`.

В данном случае я запрашиваю тип информации "**KMTQAITYPE_GETSEGMENTSIZE**" и получаю структуру "**D3DKMT_SEGMENTSIZEINFO**" с тремя 8-байтными членами, поэтому передаю размер буфера = 8*3.

```
struct D3DKMT_SEGMENTSIZEINFO
  DedicatedVideoMemorySize  dq  0  ;// Out. размер памяти, выделенной из видеоадаптера
  DedicatedSystemMemorySize dq  0  ;// Out. размер апертуры, выделенной из ОЗУ для графики
  SharedSystemMemorySize    dq  0  ;// Out. общая доступная видео-память
ends
```

Как-правило, в первом члене LONGLONG лежит размер памяти видеокарты, а чтобы получить общий, выделенный для графических нужд ресурс, нужно сложить все/эти три значения. Как показала практика, запрос WMI выше возвращает именно сумму данной структуры.

---

Что-же касается чтения версии DirectX, то в сети встречаются достаточно громоздкие варианты, чуть-ли не в сотню сишных строк. Меня это никак не вдохновило, поэтому я пошёл иным путём.

Если заглянуть в системную папку system32, можно обнаружить в ней файлы типа: d3d9.dll, d3d10.dll, d3d11.dll, d3d12.dll. Каждая из этих библиотек поставляется вместе с соответствующей версией DirectX, так-что начиная с 12 я просто через `LoadLibrary()` в цикле пытаюсь загрузить эти либы в своё пространство и если ошибка, то перехожу к следующей 11 и т.д. Вариант "топорный" и не позволяет получить версию-минор типа v11.1, но мне это и не нужно было - достаточно лишь мажор. Алго работает от Win7(х32), до Win10(x64).